# Jmeter- How to pass Comma separated String as 1 value through parametrization

Tags: jmeter

From a csv file, I need to pass

> 224,329,429

as a single value to one of the parameter in HTTP request.
I have parameterized using CSV data config. But, only 224 is getting passed.

I want 224,329,429 to be treated as a single value.

Please let me know how do I achieve this. Should I change anything in CSV config or CSV file to make this work?

Comment: I also changed Delimeter in CSV Data Config to @ and tried, but no luck

Comment: Also, tried by applying Quote in csv file, no luck

Comment: Each line of your csv files contains data like "224,329,429", right?

Comment: It is possible. In this case, I have only one line with 5 parameters. Out of this, Two parameters take multiple inputs - Each of these two parameter  takes 500 values in its http request and they are separated by commas.

Comment: And you are correct, it has data like "224,329,429"

Comment: Could you show an example of one line?

Comment: RESOURCEID,STARTDATE,ENDDATE,R4RESOURCEID

Comment: Could you use something like | (pipe sign) between your variables and put that in delimiter in CSV config?

Comment: I did replace , to | in CSV. I also changed the delimiter to | in the CSV data Config parameter. But, it takes only first value. My CSV file looks like as below. For Example, Resourceiid is the column header and the values are 304236|304231|304226|304221 . The http request is taking only 304236

Comment: In View Results Tree, I see this (Have copied few of it here...) > POST data: 
Type=4&ShowHeader=false&ViewIID=-1&Resourceiids=%22304236%2C304231%2C304226%2C304221%2C304216%2C304211%2C304206%2C304201%2C304196%2C304191%2C304186%2C304181%2C304176%2C304171%2C304166%2C304161%2C304156%2C304151%2C304146%2C304141%2C304136%2C304131%2C304126%2C304121%2C304116%2C304111%2C304106%2C304101%2C304096%2C304091%2C304086.                    Response data displays this. 
            <b>Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request.</b><br />

Comment: Is it because I see %22 and %2C in the request. How do I take it off? Please help

Comment: I will have to mostly replace %22 with , How can I do that, please advise

Comment: Use a escape sequence character by doubling it.

Comment: Did not get you, can you please give example

Comment: And should that be done in CSV file?

Comment: First option is change the delimiter in CSV file. Second option is surround the value using double quotes. e.g. "value1,value2" and select `Allow Quoted Data?` as True in CSV Data Set Config.

Comment: I have tried both these options and not working as mentioned above in my earlier comments. Not sure of other alternatives. Please suggest

Comment: The same value as you mentioned is working for me. Cover the values with double quotes and select `Allow Quoted Data` as True in CSV Data Set Config. Please post the error screenshot. Thanks!

Comment: @  NaveenKumar Namachivayam, Thank you. Your suggestion helped and it works.

Comment: @NaveenKumarNamachivayam, select Allow Quoted Data as True in CSV Data Set Config worked for me.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just use [__StringFromFile()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile) function instead of using CSV Data Set Config.

The __StringFromFile() function reads next line from the file each time it's being called so it seems to be a lot easier to stick to it for particular your scenario.

The syntax is as simple as `${__StringFromFile(/path/to/your/file.csv,,,)}` and the function can be used **anywhere** in the script, i.e. directly in the request parameter section.

See [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) to get started with the JMeter Functions concept and comprehensive information on the above and other JMeter functions.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your delimiter to a *not used character* e.g. `@`

In that way you will be able to get full line for every request

Answer (score 0):

Use ${**__FileToString**(dummy.csv,,payloadvar)} function. It makes the file independent that mean you can use any file extension example: .txt, .csv, .excel etc..

Just keep the string in dummy.csv and it will fetch the whole string.
benefit of using this function is, it will not consider comma's so in case your string has comma separated values then this is the best option.

Answer (score -1):

Just use %2C in the place of comma.